# Remove <h1> with angular ng-if when go to specific route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-if

I am new at **JavaScript** and **AngularJS**. I catch a problem. I want to remove h1 tag when go to /main route. I know that i must use `ng-if` and expression with `$location` at controller.

```
<html>
<body>
...
<h1 ng-if "? ">
    sometext
</h1>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
...
</html>
```

What expression i must use to remove this , or i must write function at controller to check.Thank you in advance

Comment: Here is the documentation from Angular JS about path and routes, and how you can access to them :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

You pretty much have a solution for everything you can ask. If you don't understand some paragraph after thinking several times about it, feel free to ask !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function on `ng-if` which would check current URL / state of application and will return true/false based on condition result

```
<h1 ng-if="toShowHeader()">MY HEADER</h1>

$scope.toShowHeader = function(){
   return $location.path() === '/login';
   //return $state.current.name === 'login'; //if you have ui-router in place.
};
```

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped, Thanks & Cheers :)